# MATLAB findpeaks using minpeakdistance

Tags: matlab, find, local, mathematical-optimization

Suppose that I have a data set that contains a cyclical event and I am identifying a threshold (peaks) to separate each event (to eventually find the coefficient of variation).

I have multiple trials of this data - the speed of these events is sometimes significantly faster than others. This data is also a bit noisy, so some 'false local maximas' are sometimes picked up if I don't set the 'minpeakdistance' constraint within the 'findpeaks' function.

I am trying to find a way to ensure that regardless of speed, I am finding 'true local maximas'. I have been visually inspecting each trial to ensure that I have identified only true peaks - if I have also identified false peaks, I have been adjusted the mpd value for that specific trial - but this is literally going to take days.

Any suggestions?

Example:

For most trials of my collection, the following line of code only identifies true maximas:

```
mpd = 'minpeakdistance';

eval(['[t' num2str(a) '.Mspine.pks(:,1),t' num2str(a) '.Mspine.locs] = findpeaks(t' num2str(a) '.Mspine.xyz(:,1), mpd,25);']);
```

But, for trial 11, they are moving much faster, so the mpd has to be adjusted to 9; however, if I apply an mpd value of 9 to all of the trials, it will pick up false local maximas.

Comment: You could smooth it first. If your data has a fixed periodicity you could guess it from the power spectrum of your data (say, by choosing mpd = 0.5/max_freq_in_power_spectrum, perhaps only consider sensible ranges first). Also, your eval thing is rather ugly. If you insist on using eval, just do it on the variable name,

Answer (score 0):

theI would go over to the frequency domain to find this "cyclical event". Specifically, if you know the rate at which data is sampled/generated, using a FFT will indicate the relative strengths of all periodic events in your data. Have a look at: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fft.html